# How to remove Ag Grid loading spinner

Tags: css, reactjs, ag-grid

I am using ag-grid `rowModelType=serverSide` and currently my overlay when the data is loading has a spinner that looks like the following image below. I want to remove that spinner. I tried `hideOverlay()` but apparently that spinner is not an overlay. Not sure how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [document](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/overlays/), Overlays are not used when using Row Models other than the Client-Side Row Model.

To customize the loading when `rowModelType=serverSide`, you need to customize the [Loading Cell Renderer](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-loading-cell-renderer/).

```js
class CustomLoadingCellRenderer {
    init(params) {
        this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
        this.eGui.innerHTML = `
            <div class="ag-custom-loading-cell" style="padding-left: 10px; line-height: 25px;">  
                <span>${params.loadingMessage} </span>
            </div>
        `;
    }
    getGui() {
        return this.eGui;
    }
}

const gridOptions = {
    loadingCellRenderer: CustomLoadingCellRenderer,
    loadingCellRendererParams: {
        loadingMessage: 'Loading',
    },
    rowModelType: "serverSide",
    serverSideDatasource: datasource
}

const App = () => {
    const [rowData] = useState([]);
    const [columnDefs] = useState(columns);

    return (
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: 400, width: 600 }}>
            <AgGridReact gridOptions={gridOptions} rowData={rowData} columnDefs={columnDefs}
                modules={[ServerSideRowModelModule]}
            ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
    );
};
```